# Can thumbcache.dll safely be removed from Windows 2008 Server R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dll

We have a product that has a conflict with thumbcache.dll.  Can thumbcache.dll safely be removed from Windows 2008 Server R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get a whole variety of problems if you remove it. But they might be better than your app not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problems?  Or do you know where there is a reference to this dll?  Thanks!

Comment: You'll get DCOM failures in the event log. I'm not sure how Explorer will handle thumbnails for picture file (they wont work obviously, but I don't believe explorer will crash). DCDiag doesn't work (not a problem if it's not a domain controller). MS Office will crash on files that contain pictures. Printing may not work. Other programs may not work.

Comment: Thanks.  If you know of a reference to the dll, that would be helpful!